# 'rake db:migrate:up VERSION=' aborts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I created a migration. I am trying to run it by:

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=
```

It raises the following error:

```
D, [2018-06-03T13:20:41.295098 #2257] DEBUG -- : ** [Raven] Sending event 2a32cb0c249acd2efde26ce6453a2d77 to Sentry
D, [2018-06-03T13:20:41.343397 #2257] DEBUG -- : ** [Raven] Raven HTTP Transport connecting to https://app.getsentry.com
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `last_comment' for #<Rake::Application:0x007fb71d8a76a0>
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:101:in `define'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:78:in `initialize'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.2/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake:11:in `new'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.2/lib/rspec/rails/tasks/rspec.rake:11:in `<top (required)>'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.0.2/lib/rspec-rails.rb:13:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `instance_exec'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each_registered_block'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:237:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:437:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:437:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in `load_tasks'
/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: (1) Why `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=`? Usually you'd just `rake db:migrate` to run the new migration. (2) What does the new migration look like?

Comment: What were you hoping to accomplish by not supplying the version?

Comment: @Sergio: I have run the command with the version number

Comment: @mu: Here is the new migration:
```
class NAME < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
         dir.up do
             ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE tabel_name")
         end
       end
  end
end
```
`rake db:migrate`  shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

Specify version when migrating. This is good is you want to migrate only specific version of your migration. If you want to migrate all pending migration you can just say rake db:migrate.
Example:

```
 rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20120820165642
```

Comment: I have specified the version number, but it shows the same error

Comment: You can just say rake db:migrate if not solved please paste command you run

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the command against local rails
`rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20120820165642 RAILS_ENV=test`
works for me